# How to remote control a samsung smart TV over TCPIP

Tags: api, samsung-smart-tv

I'am searching for an API which enables me to build an app, containing a custom remote control for a samsung smart TV.
There are some API's documented at [Samsung](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/api_reference/javascript_apis/javascript_apis_cover.html), but none of them seems to provide the functions which a standard remote has.

How does the original Samsung remote app communicate? Is it an undocumented api?

Comment: i am woking on same app kindly guide me if u get any result

Comment: Any of you able to get something out of this?

Comment: No, sorry. Still the same problem: No API spec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem. I dont't know how, but the guys of openHAB implemented a working binding for samsung smart TVs. It uses exactly the interface I wanted to connect to. A reference implementation in Java is available at their Git repository https://github.com/openhab/openhab/tree/master/bundles/binding/org.openhab.binding.samsungtv